# Loading XML file into NodeJS as a JSON

Tags: javascript, xml, json, node.js, xml-parsing

I'm trying to load an XML file into my nodeJS project as a JSON and having some issued. The `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))` returns an `undefined` value.

```
var returnJSONResults = function(baseName, queryName) {
     var XMLPath = "SomeFile.xml";
     var rawJSON = loadXMLDoc(XMLPath);
    function loadXMLDoc(filePath) {
        var fs = require('fs');
        var xml2js = require('xml2js');
        var json;
        try {
            var fileData = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'ascii');

            var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
            parser.parseString(fileData.substring(0, fileData.length), function (err, result) {
            json = JSON.stringify(result);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
        });

        console.log("File '" + filePath + "/ was successfully read.\n");
        return json;
    } catch (ex) {...}
 }
}();
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here but it is either unable to read the file (but doesn't return an error) or does't know how to stringify it.

Thnx.

UPDATE:
changed the `parser.parseString` and it is working now.

```
fs.readFile(__dirname + '/'+ filePath, function(err, data) {
            parser.parseString(data, function (err, result) {
                console.log(result);
                console.log('XML converted to JSON');
                tempJSON = result;
            });
        });
```

Comment: if you put `console.log(result)` just before the `json=JSON.stringify...` line - what do you see? i.e are you certain that `parser.parseString` is actually working?

Comment: Yes, I get the full XML file as it was saved.

Comment: but shouldn't you get json instead of xml, if `parser.parseString` is working as expected?

Comment: Any chance we can get the contents of the XML file? I am convinced at this stage it's an error in your XML. Also, can you `console.log(err)` in that handler function?

Comment: Altered the `parser.parseString` and it seems to be working now.

Comment: The xml passed a validator (used the one on W3Schools - http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp) Either way I got it working and updated the original question. Though if I have to be honest I'm not 100% sure what the problem was :)

Comment: Glad its working for you, maybe it was the ascii encoding you specified for reading the file, who knows :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the following runnable...
Copied your code. not many changes....
It works...
I suspect your XML has something wrong in it.... I created a simple valid XML...
If you add your XML there we can go further to see what's wrong.
Hope that helps.

Runnable link: [Runnable Link Here](http://runnable.com/U4XhQL8RBlweSlcc/loading-xml-file-into-nodejs-as-a-json-for-node-js-and-hello-world)

Shahar.

Answer (score 0):

It seems in your code  you doesn't have any variable "obj" . Form your code i think

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(json));
```

will work.

Comment: Its a mistake in the question. Fixed it. The code oddly still doesn't work and returns `undefined`.

Comment: You can try using console.log to check  previous lines whether its working or not..Also in catch block put console.log(ex), so that u can  came to know which error r u getting..